# How to connect to Access (*. Accdb) via Entity Framework and JetEntityFrameworkProvider?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, jet-ef-provider

**I use:**
 Visual Studio 2017;
`<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />`;
EntityFramework  - 6.1.4;
JetEntityFrameworkProvider - 6.2.0;
WinForm;

MS Access - 2016;
Database - db.accdb;
Tables - Project, Task.

EntityFramework, JetEntityFrameworkProvider installed through Nuget.

**File `App.config`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>

</configuration>
```

**I changed the file `machine.config`:**
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config

```
  <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
      <add name="JetEntityFrameworkProvider" invariant="JetEntityFrameworkProvider" description="JetEntityFrameworkProvider" type="JetEntityFrameworkProvider.JetProviderFactory, JetEntityFrameworkProvider, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=756cf6beb8fe7b41" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
```

Copied the project(F6).

I do the following
[image]
[image]
 [image]
 [[image]
[image]

**Question.**
How to connect to Access (*.accdb) via Entity Framework and JetEntityFrameworkProvider?

**Update_1**
Installed "DDEX" via Nuget
[image]

**Update_2**
I downloaded the project at https://github.com/bubibubi/JetEntityFrameworkProvider
[image]

For the project "JetDdexProvider" made "Assign a startup project"
[image]

Pressed **F6**
Received errors
***Error**
exit from the ""% ProgramFiles% \ Microsoft SDKs \ Windows \ v8.0A \ Bin \ NETFX 4.0 Tools \ gacutil.exe "/ u" JetEntityFrameworkProvider "" with code 3.

**Error**
exit from the command "call" C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Microsoft Visual Studio \ 2017 \ Community2 \ Common7 \ IDE \ .. \ Tools \ vsvars32.bat "
gacutil / u JetEntityFrameworkProvider.dll "with code 9009. JetDdexProvider

**Error CS0006**
Could not find the metadata file "Z: \ vs \ csharp \ dll \ JetEntityFrameworkProvider \ 2018.05.16 \ fl \ Debug \ JetEntityFrameworkProvider.dll". JetEntityFrameworkProvider.Test Z: \ vs \ csharp \ dll \ JetEntityFrameworkProvider \ 2018.05.16 \ fl \ JetEntityFrameworkProvider.Test \ CSC 1

**Error CS0006**
Could not find the metadata file "Z: \ vs \ csharp \ dll \ JetEntityFrameworkProvider \ 2018.05.16 \ fl \ Debug \ JetEntityFrameworkProvider.dll". JetEntityFrameworkProvider.Utilities Z: \ vs \ csharp \ dll \ JetEntityFrameworkProvider \ 2018.05.16 \ fl \ JetEntityFrameworkProvider.Utilities \ CSC*

Comment: For use DBFirst you need to compile from source code and install the Visual Studio extension (DDEX Provider). Your issue is related to the DDEX provider registration. You need to check install.cmd and update it with the proper registry key (related to VS 2017).

Comment: @bubi Where is the "install.cmd" file?
How to update it?

Comment: It's part of the source code. It should be in DDEX project

Comment: @bubi Installed "DDEX" via Nuget.
I did the right thing?
Sorry, but I do not understand.
  What to do next?
Updated the question.

Comment: @bubi EntityFramework, JetEntityFrameworkProvider installed through Nuget.

Comment: DDEX is not included in NuGet package. NuGet package contains only codefirst libraries. To use DDEX you need to compile the provider from source code (and fix install.cmd).

Comment: @bubi Updated the question.
See "Update_2".

What needs to be fixed in "install.cmd"?
How to perform "install.cmd" fixes?